# Getting a connect time out exception in jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to read a lot of html pages using jsoup. I have an arraylist called "allPageLinks" that keeps html page links. Here is my code:

```
Document doc;

for (int i = 0; i < allPageLinks.size(); i++) {
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(allPageLinks.get(i)).timeout(0).get();

        Element page_clips = doc.getElementById("page_clips");
        Element page_clip_content = page_clips
                .getElementById("content");
        Elements product_grid = page_clip_content
                .select(".product-list.margin-left-5");
        Elements products = product_grid.get(0).children();

        for (int j = 0; j < products.size(); j++) {
            try {
                String productName = products.get(j)
                        .getElementsByClass("name").text();
                String productPrice = products.get(j)
                        .getElementsByClass("price").text();
                String productLink = products.get(j)
                        .getElementsByClass("image").select("a")
                        .first().attr("href");
                Document newDoc = Jsoup.connect(productLink).get();
                Elements elements = newDoc.getElementsByClass("left");
                Elements productNameElement = elements.get(0)
                        .getElementsByClass("colorbox");
                String productImage = productNameElement.attr("href");
                elements = newDoc.getElementsByClass("right");
                String productId = elements.get(0)
                        .getElementsByClass("field").get(1).text();

                writer.append(productName);
                writer.append(';');
                writer.append(productPrice);
                writer.append(';');
                writer.append(productId);
                writer.append(';');
                writer.append(productImage);
                writer.append(';');
                writer.append(productLink);
                writer.append('\n');
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " " + i + " "
                        + allPageLinks.get(i) + " ICTEKICATCH");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " " + i + " "
                + allPageLinks.get(i));
    }
}
```

Even though i set connection timeout to zero, i am getting a lot of connect time out exceptions for most of the links. Can anyone help me to get rid of that exception?

Thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @eltabo yes, i am. Is that the problem?

Comment: @eltabo and if that is the problem, why am i getting the exception on some links, but not getting exception in some other links?

Comment: did you try to manually wget/curl the pages that fail? Is it the same pages that fail?

Comment: @luksch, the pages fail are random, not always the same. Can you please explain what wget/curl means? i do not know. Also, i checked some of the pages that timed out, and i saw that even though they have a timeout, that pages are read and necessary info are received, but i cannot be sure that necessary info are received for all pages that failed. so i want to get rid of the exception

Comment: wget and curl are command line tools to retrieve html pages. I wanted to ask, if you checked, if the failed pages can be retrieved via those tools in order to figure out if they can be reached at all.

Comment: @luksch thanks, yes i tried now and they are reachable

Comment: post the stack trace of the ```connect time out exceptions``` please

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add specify the timeout for this connection within the loop of the code:

```
 Document newDoc = Jsoup.connect(productLink).get();
```

Should be:

```
 Document newDoc = Jsoup.connect(productLink).timeout(0).get();
```

That is where the timeout exception is most likely occurring.